# Highly integrated RF front-end chipset RFX8055 issues

Tags: rf, filter, non-linear, intermodulation-products

In this datasheet of [RFX8055](http://www.skyworksinc.com/uploads/documents/RFX8055_204385A.pdf) (CMOS 5GHz WLAN 802.11a/n/ac RFeIC WITH PA, LNA, AND SPDT switch), they mention "5GHz Power Amplifier with Low-Pass Harmonic Filter".

1. If this filter is meant for filtering intermodulation products then it should better be bandpass filter right? (as intermodulation has sometimes \$f_1-f_2\$ low pass component too)
2. They also mention "High Power Capability for Received Signals in Bypass Mode", the mode in which LNA is bypassed. Does this just mean that the chipset is able to handle high power in LNA bypass mode or is there any other important implication?
3. Whats the purpose of "LO rejection" in this chipset? Generally, LO rejection parameter is considered in dealing with RF mixers right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, it says "Low-Pass Harmonic Filter" which means that **Harmonics** need to be filtered. Harmonics which are created in the PA. For intermodulation there would need to be a **mixer** in the path and there isn't after the PA. There are only non-linearities causing harmonics of the wanted signal.

2) When high level input signals are present the LNA could distort and/or saturate and this causes intermodulation products. So **if** the wanted signal is strong enough the LNA is not needed and can be switched off. This shifts the usable dynamic range up so larger (unwanted) signals are less problematic.

3) Maybe that sentence about "LO rejection" concerns on-chip filters preventing LO signals from reaching the LNA and/or LO signals reaching the PA. But there's no mention elsewhere in the datasheet about LO so it is unclear how effective this "LO Rejection" is. In my opinion you should ignore the "LO Rejection" remark as the chip does not have any LO signal connected to it. Also, it does not "know" what frequency you're using as LO in the rest of your system. I think this is a marketing phrase and should be ignored.

Comment: yeah, I understand that only low pass filter is needed to remove harmonics. But if the PA is non-linear then intermodulation components would be present there, right? (e.g. as this [article](http://www.electronicdesign.com/communications/understanding-intermodulation-distortion-measurements) explains) Is there no need to remove those components lying in low-frequency region?

Comment: If I am using 802.11ac which occupies 160MHz BW then \$f_1-f_2\$ would be 160MHz so there would be a IMD component at 160 MHz.

Comment: That article refers to mixing f1 and f2 which and then you indeed get intermod products because different harmonics mix. In a PA with distortion you do not mix 2 different signals, the mixing then happens only on f1 with f1 so the end results are only multiples of f1 which are harmonics, not intermod products. The same happens with f2, it will only mix with itself. For IM products you need for example the 3rd harminic of f1 mixing with the 2nd harmonic of f2 and that doesn't happen with one input signal like a PA.

Comment: Also you cannot easily filter out the IM products, a filter for 160 MHz at 5 GHz has a Q of 5G/160M = 31 which will be a challenge. That 160 MHz signal will not be created and even if it did, it will not pass the usual matching network present around the PA and antenna.

Comment: Actually, you do get intermod generated in a PA, harmonics are easily filtered and for the rest it is generally the odd order terms that cause a problem being as they lie in band. If the signal applied to a PA was a pure tone then only harmonics would matter, but a pure tone conveys zero information so typically a PA has many simultaneous signals applied.... The output match is typically not all that broadband, and even if it were the antenna for GHz bands tend not to radiate so well down near DC.